# How to count the number of files in a sub folder with a specific name using C#?

Tags: c#, directory

I have a path structure that looks like this:

```
Main_Folder
      ***Sub_Folder1***
           **1) FOLDER_Y**
                 Folder1
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 Folder2
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 FolderN
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
           **2) FOLDER_X**
                 Folder1
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 Folder2
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
           **3) FOLDER_Z**
                 Folder1
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 Folder2
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
   ***Sub_Folder2***
           **1) FOLDER_Y**
                 Folder1
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 Folder2
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 FolderN
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
           **2) FOLDER_X**
                 Folder1
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 Folder2
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
           **3) FOLDER_Z**
                 Folder1
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 Folder2
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
   ***Sub_Folder3***
           **1) FOLDER_Y**
                 Folder1
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 Folder2
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 FolderN
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
           **2) FOLDER_X**
                 Folder1
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 Folder2
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
           **3) FOLDER_Z**
                 Folder1
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
                 Folder2
                   picture1.png
                   picture2.png
                   picturen.png
```

> ```
> > Desired mock output: 
> > FOLDER_Y # files: 27 
> > FOLDER_X # files: 18
> > FOLDER_Z # files: 18
> ```

I basically want the user to input a path to the **main folder**, then iterate through each sub_folder. Then output the total number of files in ALL Folder_Y’s from all the sub folders. And the same for Folder_X, Folder_Z.

I’ve tried several methods unsuccessfully.

```
public void getFOLDER_Y(string strPath)
{
    string partialName = "FOLDER_Y";

    DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);
    FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + partialName + "*.*");
    DirectoryInfo[] dirsInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetDirectories("*" + partialName + "*.*");

    foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
    {
        string fullName = foundFile.FullName;
        richtxt_results.Text += fullName + "\n";

    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo foundDir in dirsInDir)
    {
        string fullName = foundDir.FullName;
        richtxt_results.Text += fullName + "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public static void CountFiles(string path)
    {
        int xFileCount = 0;
        int yFileCount = 0;
        int zFileCount = 0;

        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach(string file in files)
        {
            string folder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(file)).Name;
            if (folder == "FOLDER_X")
                xFileCount++;
            if (folder == "FOLDER_Y")
                yFileCount++;
            if (folder == "FOLDER_Z")
                zFileCount++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("X Files : {0}", xFileCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Y Files : {0}", yFileCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Z Files : {0}", zFileCount);
    }
```

Few tips:

- If you want to search for a specific type of files (say, for example, only text files) then you can pass search pattern to Directory.GetFiles(), such as "*.txt" instead of "*.*".
- If you want to make this more generic, instead of just hardcoding your folder names you could pass that as a parameter.

So I would really use this function, and call it with whatever folder name you want:

```
    public static int CountFiles(string path, string folderToSearch)
    {
        int fileCount = 0;

        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string folder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(file)).Name;
            if (folder == folderToSearch)
                fileCount++;
        }

        return fileCount;
    }
```

Then call it like so:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int xFiles = CountFiles("path goes here", "FOLDER_X");
        int yFiles = CountFiles("path goes here", "FOLDER_Y");
        int zFiles = CountFiles("path goes here", "FOLDER_Z");
    }
```

EDIT: Made a small change to how you get the immediate directory name.

EDIT2: Edited to incorporate the suggestion by @MickyD.

EDIT3: This would pass your most recent requirement.

```
    public static int CountFiles2(string path, string folderToSearch)
    {
        int fileCount = 0;
        var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, folderToSearch, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            if (files != null)
                fileCount += files.Count();
        }

        return fileCount;
    }
```

Comment: **Note** - you should use **EnumerateFiles** when dealing with large number of files particularly with child folders because it returns an **IEnumerable<>** rather than an array.

Comment: I did not know that and seems like a useful piece of information to know. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. However, I am getting an error at   **string folder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(file)).Name;** It is somehow searching for the folder inside the directory that my C# project is on instead of the path. Even though I am calling the function with the appropriate path.

Comment: @AR.Torres did you pass the correct path in place of _"path goes here"_? I suggest you use the second method I gave which I tested. Please double check. What's the error you get? It's highly questionable because if you go inside the `foreach` loop then that means you already have found files wherever you're looking.

Comment: Yes, there was an issue with the path so that is now solved. But I forgot to mentioned the folders there are other other folders and I want to get the count of those, so right now your code is outputting 0.           So lets say FOLDER_X has 20 folders and inside each X number files I am trying to otput the combined X number of each  folder named FOLDER_X within the path if that makes sense. So basically from the path, go to only one child down on each folder search for the name, if it matches then count ALL files inside that folder and accumulate it.

Comment: Well that's a different question now. You should first think clearly and write your question.

Anyway I don't quite understand what you're saying here; do you want the count of all files inside all subfolders found under FOLDER_X, FOLDER_Y etc, or does your FOLDER_X contain multiple folders inside it some of which are named FOLDER_X, and you want the count of files inside those sub-level FOLDER_X? Please clearly define your requirement.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I have updated the file structure on the question. I want to count all the files in all folders of FOLDER_X,FOLDER_Y,FOLDER_Z regardless if the name of each folder inside those. Let me know if you understand it. I appreciate your time greatly!!

Comment: OK I understand now. But instead of waiting for a code sample from me I want you think _think_ how you might solve the problem. I'll post a code sample later if you still can't figure it out, but right now I'll just give you some pointers. You can easily modify the CountFiles() to achieve your objective. As it is now, it enumerates all files inside all subdirectories under root, then count files only if the immediate directory which the file resides in is equal to whatever you pass in your `folderToSearch`.

Contd...

Comment: Now what you should instead do is, find the topmost directories under your root directory that's named `FOLDER_X`, `FOLDER_Y` etc. Once you find those directories, then enumerate files under each of those just as we've done here.
To get you started, `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()` will help you go in the right direction.

Comment: public static int CountFiles(string path, string folderToSearch)
        {
            int fileCount = 0;
            List <string> direcs = new List<string> (Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path,folderToSearch));
            foreach (var dir in direcs)
            {
                var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    
                        fileCount++;
                }



            }
    
            return fileCount;
        }

Comment: You're almost there. Your logic is now correct, the problem is your parameters. For `EnumerateDirectories` you need to pass `SearchOption.AllDirectories` so that it would list files in subdirectories too. Then in `EnumerateFiles`, you must pass `"*.*"` so it would find all files. Let me update my answer.